# jquery(selector) how to select the last element from two different classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

for the following html

```
<div>
    <div class="col1" >
         I dont want to select this
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
         I dont want to select this
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
         I dont want to select this
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
         I dont want to select this
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
         I WANT to select this
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I select the last element with two different class names?

Tried using

```
$("col1:last,col2:last)
```

but it gives back 2 elements

tried

```
$("col1,col2:last")
```

and this gives all col1 and last of col2

Comment: hmm, I don't know what you mean. Do you mean a div with both "col1" and "col2"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First get all elements with any of the class names, then pick the last one:

```
$('.col1,.col2').filter(':last')
```

Answer (score 1):

try the [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method.

`$(".col1,.col2").last();`

Comment: but I want the last div that has one of the two class names(not one)

Comment: I see what you mean, how about that?

Comment: jquery seems to think last() is a method

Comment: nice, learned something new. last() is exactly what I'm looking for. In my case it won't help though since I'm using 1.3. Thanks a lot Hunter for your time and effort!

Comment: `$('.col1, .col2').slice(-1).eq(0)`. But it'd be better to upgrade to 1.4 if you can. `last()` as a method (or this alternative) is somewhat more efficient than filtering, and considerably more efficient than including a non-standard Sizzle-only selector such as `:last` in the query itself.